# How to create ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to create ExpandableListView. It contains 2 rows, the row children are textviews & imagebutton & toggle button. on click of the imagebutton the childviews should be displayed to a particular selected row.

How should I do this with ExpandableListView?

My problem is that I have to set 2 rows in one line and that should be keep in a for loop.. How should I do this with ExpandableListView.?
Every row has again 2 rows. This is dynamically I am adding... Previously I was done this with tablelayout, but i am not getting proper result as per my requirement.

So some people suggested in this forum, better to use listview instead of tablelayout..

Can anyone please help me..?

Comment: hello can you explain why you are doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use layout inflaters to set as many rows as you want. You don't have to do it dynamically, I think.